# (The) Spring Festival is a national holiday in China

Tags: sentence-construction

Spring festival lasts for 15 days, during the festival, most people have their days off.

So may I say 'Spring Festival is a national holiday in China'? Thank you!

Comment: A National Holiday must be typically recognised as such. For example, the period between Christmas and New Year's Day is a time when many workers are off, but this doesn't mean they're all national holidays.

Comment: "A public holiday, national holiday or legal holiday is a holiday generally established by law and is usually a non-working day during the year... French Journée de solidarité envers les personnes âgées (Day of solidarity with the elderly) is a notable exception. This holiday became a mandatory working day although the French Council of State confirmed it remains a holiday." - [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holiday)

Comment: On the side, "most people have *days off*" is the normal phrase to describe days where you don't have to work, go to school or other such activities.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction! I'm really sorry, I should have said that 'Spring Festival is a national holiday in China.'

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: On the side, your first sentence has what is called a "comma splice".  Your first comma is trying to connect two different sentences.  If you want to do that, you need either a coordinating conjunction (and, or, nor, but, yet, etc.) or use a semicolon or period.  I would say it as "Spring festival lasts for fifteen days.  During the festival, most people have days off."

Comment: *May* you say that?  What is holding you back?  Are you wondering about the accuracy of the sentence, the punctuation, the capitalization?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm not sure the accuracy of the sentence. I will say 'is it correct to say...' next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If "Spring Festival" is the full, official name of the holiday, then your sentence (without the leading "The") is correct.

EDIT: To determine accuracy, I would search online for a list of Chinese official holidays and see if it's included.  You can't go wrong that way.  ;)

Comment: It is like Christmas to westerners, the start of a new year and the most important festival for Chinese and some other Asian countries. I think the above sentence is incorrect.